# eclipse papyrus 2.0.0 - only advanced properties available

Tags: eclipse, papyrus

I just installed papyrus version 2.0.0. While using the papyrus perspective I can only see the advanced properties tab and no longer the other tabs. Can anyone guide me in the right direction to get all the properties "tabs" back in the property window.

[image]

Comment: I just downloaded and ran the 32 bit version (I reported the issue on 64 bit version) and there the problem does not occur. I am running this in windows 10 by the way

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the Preferences ?
Window -> Preferences -> Papyrus -> Property views